# Game Center Formatting Time

Tags: ios, game-center, gkscore

What do you set the value to be for the scoreReporter to show up as a correct time in game center leader-board.  What do you need to covert the seconds to show up properly in the leader-board.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have:

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"BestTime"] autorelease];
scoreReporter.value = TotalSeconds * 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

Seconds are fine if you have defined your leaderboard score format type to "Elapsed time - To the second". You just need

```
scoreReporter.value = TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for an answer to that everywhere but it doesn't seem to be written anywhere (certainly not in Apple's "documentation").

Comment: cant we send the time in following format to display - 00:20:25

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. With  "Elapsed time - To the second", you send the time in seconds and it is shown as hh:mm:ss in the leaderboard